# Java Math.Random() for series of numbers

Tags: java, eclipse, math, random

Is it possible to use Math.Random() in Java to obtain numbers in a series such as 10, 20, 30, 40... or 100, 200, 300....
My current implementation is Math.Random()*3*100 as I thought that would bring me numbers up to 300 that are divisible by 100.

Comment: Please explain what output you desire, and how you desire the values to be random... do you want a sequence shuffled, or do you want a random value in a certain interval?

Comment: You already got a working answer in your question?

Comment: @Berendschot Hard to tell if it works. If he doesn't like his current implementation, I think he should include what he doesn't like about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Math.random()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29) returns a `double`. You want an `int` value, so you should use the [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class. You should probably do that anyway.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int num = (rnd.nextInt(30) + 1) * 10; // 10, 20, 30, ..., 300
```

*Explanation:*

[`nextInt(30)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) returns a random number between 0 and 29 (inclusive).
`+ 1` then makes that a number between 1 and 30.
`* 10` then makes that `10, 20, 30, ..., 300`.

So, if you just want `100, 200, 300`, use:

```
int num = (rnd.nextInt(3) + 1) * 100; // 100, 200, 300
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this but only return either 100, 200 or 300?

Answer (score 2):

This code returns a random number with step 10. 0 is excluded from this, but if you want to add it, take out the +1 on the Math.random() line.

```
int step = 10;
int random = (int)(Math.random()*10+1)*step; //10 is the number of possible outcomes
System.out.println("Random with step " + step + ":" random);
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this but only return either 100, 200 or 300?

Comment: @smithcommajohn Yes it is. Just change the step to 100, ow whatever you want it to be.

Comment: so if I was to do;                                                                                           int step = 100                                                                                                  int random = (int)(Math.random*3+*step;   that would return either 100, 200 or 300?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation of Math.random()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random()) states that a call returns a

> double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0.

This means, the resulting number of your computation is between 0 and 300, but it is not of type `int`, but of type `double`. You should add a call to [Math.round](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(double)) or simply cast it to `int` and add a loop if you want to create multiple values..

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to return numbers such as 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60... the following should do this.

```
int ranNumber=(int)(Math.random()*10+1)*10;
System.out.println(ranNumber);

//sample output: 80
```

Comment: That returns numbers `0, 10, 20, ..., 100`. OP doesn't want `0`.

Comment: @Andreas Fair point! But the examples OP gave appeared to be in multiples of 10, 100, presumably 1000 and did not specify in between numbers such as 170. The code I supplied could then be easily modified to multiply by these numbers instead of e.g. `10`. Additionally, where OP did not explicitly say that 0 should be discluded I can see how it might be implied, so point taken!

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a direct way to do that but i'm sure with some manipulation we can do it. Below i have created the method `randSeries` to generate a number based off of a series. You send this method two values, a increment, which is how big you want the base of your series number to be. Then the base, which is your 10s, 20s, 30s. We are essentially generating a random number in the range you provide the method, then multiplying it by the base you sent the method to create a value that is divisible by your base.

```
    public int randSeries(int increment, int base){
        Random rand = new Random();

        int range = rand.nextInt(increment)+1; //random number
        System.out.println(range);

        int finalVal = range * base; //turning your random number into a series
        System.out.println(finalVal);

        return finalVal; //return
    }
```

**As a note ::** This method can be used to generate numbers of **ANY** base value not just 10.